# Snowflake not picking default value for timestamp

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column in snowflake of type **TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)** and I have set its default value as
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

But still in all rows, I am getting the value of this column as null.

[image]

Why is the default value not being reflected and its  giving null values?

Comment: I would suggest you check the actual INSERT that is run, you can look for it in the Query History in the Web UI. You must be INSERTing explicitly a NULL into this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not inserting NULL manually?

Here's what works for me:

```
create or replace table testX(id integer autoincrement, text string, time timestamp_tz(9) default current_timestamp());
insert into testX (text) values ('test message');
```

I get:

[image]

Then I insert a NULL value:

```
insert into testX (time) values (NULL);
```

Now I see:

[image]

Table definition looks exactly like yours:

```
describe table testX;
```

I see:

[image]